# Array.prototype method with 'undefined' Output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I don't understand why is the output is 'undefined'?

```
    JSON.stringify(a.maxKey())
```

The output is still the same even if it is used like in the above.

```js
        Array.prototype.maxKey = function (){
         Math.max.apply(Math,
           this.map(
             function(item){
               return item.key}
           )
         )
        }

        var a = [{key:1}, {key:2}] 
        alert(a.maxKey())
```

Comment: The problem is your `maxKey` method which returns `undefined`, not `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

You miss `return` keyword.

```js
Array.prototype.maxKey = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(item => item.key));
}

var a = [{ key: 1}, { key: 2}];
console.log(a.maxKey())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is hard to be rookie!